# Komodo Edit - HTML reformatting / Tidy

Tags: html, tidy, htmltidy, komodoedit

Is there a simple way to reformat my HTML from within Komodo Edit or to automate the process against Tidy?

Something like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Visual Studio would be brilliant. I am presently running Ubuntu with Tidy installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a solution that just straight up works, do the following:

- Pop open the toolbox panel on the right.
- Click on the gear and select New Macro. Name it what you like.

Get the macro code here:

*Komodo edit macro (404)*

It includes the code from http://jsbeautifier.org/ and works like a charm...

Next is to set up a keystroke:

- Select your new macro in the toolbox
- Now go to key bindings

  Type a sequence and it will tell you if the sequence you typed is available. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> because they are near each other.

Comment: By the way, if you want the output of jsbeautifier to look like the Ctrl-k, Ctrl-d formatting of Visual Studio, edit the macro and go to the 'JavaScript' case.  Now change the indent_size to 4, change the brace_style to "end-expand" and add "good_stuff: true" at the end.

Answer (score 7):

I [found this formatting script (macro)](http://community.activestate.com/forum/format-document-script) and adapted it for my personal use with the latest Komodo Edit (v6.1.0). It works well and I included the JavaScript formatting provided by a commentator, but I think it may only work with Komodo IDE. It's unimportant for my purposes.

Perhaps someone out there can find a universal improvement (using something like [HTML Tidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy)).

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view) { komodo.view.setFocus(); }

var formatter;
var language = komodo.document.language;
switch (language) {
    case 'Perl':
        formatter = 'perltidy -i=2 -pt=2 -l=0';
        break;
    case 'XML':
    case 'XUL':
    case 'XLST':
        formatter = 'tidy -q -xml -i -w 80';
        break;
    case 'HTML':
        formatter = 'tidy -q -asxhtml -i -w 120';
        break;
  //case 'JavaScript':
  //    ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.selectAll();
  //    ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.replaceSel(js_beautify(ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.text, {indent_size: 2}));
  //    return null;
  default:
        alert("I don't know how to tidy " + language);
        return null;
}

// Save current cursor position
var currentPos = komodo.editor.currentPos;

try {
    // Save the file. After the operation you can check what changes where made by
    // File -> Show Unsaved Changes
    komodo.doCommand('cmd_save');

    // Group operations into a single undo
    komodo.editor.beginUndoAction();

    // Select entire buffer and pipe it into formatter.
    komodo.doCommand('cmd_selectAll');
    Run_RunEncodedCommand(window, formatter + " {'insertOutput': True, 'operateOnSelection': True}");

     // Restore cursor. It will be close to the where it started depending on how the text was modified.
     komodo.editor.gotoPos(currentPos);

    // On Windows, when the output of a command is inserted into an edit buffer it has Unix line ends.
    komodo.doCommand('cmd_cleanLineEndings');
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
finally {
    // Must end undo action or we may corrupt edit buffer
    komodo.editor.endUndoAction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a command to run to replace a selection of HTML with the tidy version. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the command window and enter `tidy -utf8 -asxhtml -i` for the command which formats indented XHTML using UTF-8 encoding.

Check the two boxes to "Pass selection as input" and "Insert output". You can also specify custom key bindings there.

Example screenshot: http://grab.by/8C3t

Answer (score 1):

The [answer that TAOcode made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689287/komodo-edit-html-reformatting-tidy/5068498#5068498) is great, but in newer versions of Komodo a few things have changed, so here is my update to the code to make it work again:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(3);
if (komodo.view) { 
    komodo.view.setFocus(); 
}

var formatter;
var language = komodo.view.language;
switch (language) {
    case 'Perl':
        formatter = 'perltidy -i=2 -pt=2 -l=0';
        break;
    case 'XML':
    case 'XUL':
    case 'XLST':
        formatter = 'tidy -q -xml -i -w 500';
        break;
    case 'HTML':
        formatter = 'tidy -q -asxhtml -i -w 120';
        break;
  //case 'JavaScript':
  //    ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.selectAll();
  //    ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.replaceSel(js_beautify(ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.text, {indent_size: 2}));
  //    return null;
  default:
      alert("I don't know how to tidy " + language);
      return null;
}

// Save the current cursor position
var currentPos = komodo.editor.currentPos;

try {
    // Save the file. After the operation you can check what changes where made by
    // File -> Show Unsaved Changes
    komodo.doCommand('cmd_save');

    // Group operations into a single undo
    komodo.editor.beginUndoAction();

    // Select the entire buffer and pipe it into the formatter.
    komodo.doCommand('cmd_selectAll');
    ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, formatter + " {'insertOutput': True, 'operateOnSelection': True}");

     // Restore the cursor. It will be close to the where it started, depending on how the text was modified.
     komodo.editor.gotoPos(currentPos);

    // On Windows, when the output of a command is inserted into an edit buffer it has Unix line ends.
    komodo.doCommand('cmd_cleanLineEndings');
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
finally {
    // Must end undo action or may corrupt edit buffer
    komodo.editor.endUndoAction();
}
```

The big differences are in line 5: komodo.document.language becomes komodo.view.language and line 40: Run_RunEncodedCommand becomes ko.run.runEncodedCommand

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to menu *Toolbox* → *Add* → *New Command*
2. Enter the Tidy command line arguments in the Run field:

   ```
    tidy -config tidy_config_html.txt
   ```
3. Check all the boxes
4. Enter the path to Tidy in the `Start In` field
5. Click the *Key Binding* tab
6. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> as the *New Key Sequence*
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>