# komodo - correct identation, simple question

Tags: html, komodo

How i can apply a simple correct identation to all of my code? like the eclipse for example...

there is possible, right?

thanks

Comment: Komodo indentation problems made me switch to a different IDE. Still can not belive how ActiveState dares to sell such uncompleted and unstable product as such. What a waste of money.

Comment: i have the Komodo edit, not the ide suite. I can't believe that program don't have a simple tool to do a correct indentation...

Comment: what ide you use bioffe? there is very important to me the identation, thanks

Comment: You may have better chance of getting a response at the ActiveState Community Forum: http://community.activestate.com/forums/komodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use external code formatter via [macro](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/macro-to-reformat-files)

Comment: relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689287/komodo-edit-html-reformatting-tidy